# Confusion regarding the versioning of Cordova

Tags: cordova, version, splash-screen, hybrid

I am a newbie in mobile app development and had to take over a hybrid mobile app project i.e. using Cordova.

Per discussion with an experienced developer I learned that version 4.0 of Cordova is new and has a different handling of splash screens, which is something I need.

However when running the command `cordova -v` on my Mac I notice that the version used in the project is `6.0.0`. Further looking around [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3562?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20fixVersion%20in%20releasedVersions()%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC) provides the impression that both - version 4.0.0 and 6.0.0 - are unreleased versions of Cordova.

So do I use with version 6.0.0 one of the latest version, which can be named "stable" too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova 6.0.0 is a stable release and working perfectly with Android and iOS have a look on [this](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/)

Comment: With your help, I now know what version 4 of Cordova means pointed out by the aforementioned experienced developer - it is cordova-_ios_.